# Split big FO to smaller PDFs

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

[image: Big_FO_File]

I have a big table (black borders on picture) lets say 2.5 x A4 Format.
Is it possible to split/divide/crop big table to smaller segments (red borders on picture) to get PDF file contains A4 formatted pages?

Comment: You might be able to do something like this w/o re-calculating the complex information by using the fop intermediate xml format and copy/crop inside that one...but no precise idea, you'd have to check the docs [Area Tree](https://wiki.apache.org/xmlgraphics-fop/AreaTreeXMLDocumentation)

Comment: If your toolchain supports Form XObjects, you could effectively have several pages refer back to this one.  Otherwise, if you don't mind Python in your toolchain, I can post an answer that would do this for you.

Comment: Are you saying that your only opportunity to modify the data is after it is XSL FO? Or do you have programmatic access to the XML that is making the XSL FO?

Comment: I have access to both, but pre-process (generating XSL-FO) is quite complicated and shouldn't be changed. @Hobbes idea is the closest one, but is there option to no-copy whole content for every page.

Comment: BTW. there is no python in toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.

- Create 3 page sequences
- render the table in each page sequence, in a block-container wide enough for the whole table (i.e. on the first page, the table will run off the right side of the page)
- in the first sequence, render the table normally
- in the second and third sequence, give the table an offset:
  `<fo:block-container left="-297mm">` (or 2x 297 mm for the third page sequence)

Comment: Very interesting but also very expensive idea. But there isn't more other solutions I think.